# CUDA_HOME environment variable didn't work

Tags: python, pytorch

I am a student, and when I was reproducing a paper, I encountered the following situation:Please tell me how I should modify it

```
PS D:\CorrI2P-main\CorrI2P-main - test2\index_max_ext> pip install .
Processing d:\corri2p-main\corri2p-main - test2\index_max_ext
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "D:\CorrI2P-main\CorrI2P-main - test2\index_max_ext\setup.py", line 17, in <module>
          ext_modules=[CUDAExtension('index_max', ['index_max.cpp', 'index_max_cuda.cu'])],
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1074, in CUDAExtension
          library_dirs += library_paths(cuda=True)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1208, in library_paths
          paths.append(_join_cuda_home(lib_dir))
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 2407, in _join_cuda_home
          raise OSError('CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set. '
      OSError: CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set. Please set it to your CUDA install root.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried adding the CUDA_HOME environment variable, but it didn't work.

Comment: _I tried adding the CUDA_HOME environment variable, but it didn't work_ Are we supposed to guess what you tried?

Comment: Indeed, as mentioned by @JohnGordon, what did you try? How did you attempt to add the environment? Did you reboot your computer after setting the environment variable? Additionally, it would be helpful to indicate which OS you are using, since they likely have different ways of adding environment variables.

Comment: I used Windows, in"Edit system environment variables"，I also reboot my computer after setting the environment variable

Comment: Do you see the value you set when you do `echo %CUDA_HOME%` in cmd?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I have the same problem and I do see the value when I do `echo %CUDA_HOME%`. I've also set this environment variable inside the Visual Studio debug properties. The syntax isn't clear for me, but I did `CUDA_HOME=C:\CUDA\v12.1`. It still claims that `CUDA_HOME` is *not set*. Don't get that.